# How to get the information from an api and display it on the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom, fetch-api

I'm trying to get the stuff in my API to show up in the DOM. I keep getting an undefined but I know it's there. It shows up in my console. I just don't know what other extra things I need to do when the objects I want are nested into another array and how would I even get that onto the DOM.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.getElementById('songs').addEventListener('click', getSongs)

  //getSongs()
})

function getSongs() {
  let info = document.getElementById('info')
  let songList = document.getElementById('song-list')
  //info.innerHTML = ""
  songList.innerHTML = ""
    fetch('https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=K-Pop')
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => {
        data.results.map(song => { 
          //console.log(song)
          songList.innerHTML += `
            <li>
             <a href="#" data-name="${song.trackName}"
             data-id="${song.trackId}"> ${song.trackName} </a>
            </li>
          `
        })
        attachLinks()
    })
}

function attachLinks() {
  const songs = document.querySelectorAll('li a')
  songs.forEach(song => {
    song.addEventListener('click', displaySong)
  })
}

function displaySong(event) {
  console.log(event.target)
  let songList = document.getElementById('song-list')
  let info = document.getElementById('info')
  /*songList.innerHTML = `<h1>Song Name:</h1>
                        <p>${event.dataset.trackName}</p>
                        <h2>Artist Name:</h2>
                        <p>${event.dataset.artistName}</p>
                        <h3>Release Date:</h3>
                        <p>${event.dataset.releaseDate}</p>`*/
  songList.innerHTML = ""
  info.innerHTML = ""
  fetch(`https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=K-Pop/${event.target.dataset.id}`)
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(song  => {
        //console.log(song)
          info.innerHTML += `
          <h1>${song.trackName}</h1>
          <h3>Artist Name: </h3>
          <p>${song.artistName}</p>
          <h3>Release Date: </h3>
          <p>${song.releaseDate}</p>
        `
        })
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Music</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"/>
    
    </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Music</h1>
            <h2 id='input'>K-Pop</h2>
            <button id="songs">All songs</button>
            <hr>
            <br>
        <div id="main">
            <ul id="song-list">

            </ul>
        <div id="info">

        </div>
        </div>
            <script src="index.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

This is what all the data from the API looks like:

[image]

Comment: If you uncomment the `console.log(song)`, you'll see that it has the value `{ "resultCount": 0, "results": [] }`. This object doesn't have `.trackName`, `.artistName` or `.releaseDate` properties. It seems you are doing a `/search` again when you should be fetching the details of a specific song by id, check the documentation of the itunes API again to see how the proper URL looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the second call is made to the wrong endpoint

Try changing this call

```js
`https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=K-Pop/${event.target.dataset.id}`
```

For this

```js
`https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=${event.target.dataset.id}`;
```

This should return some json in this form if we expect `event.target.dataset.id` to be '1574770128'

```json
{
    "resultCount": 1,
    "results":
    [
        {
            "wrapperType": "track",
            "kind": "song",
            "artistId": 883131348,
            "collectionId": 1574770126,
            "trackId": 1574770128,
            "artistName": "BTS",
            "collectionName": "Permission to Dance - Single",
            "trackName": "Permission to Dance",
            "collectionCensoredName": "Permission to Dance - Single",
            "trackCensoredName": "Permission to Dance",
            "artistViewUrl": "https://music.apple.com/us/artist/bts/883131348?uo=4",
            "collectionViewUrl": "https://music.apple.com/us/album/permission-to-dance/1574770126?i=1574770128&uo=4",
            "trackViewUrl": "https://music.apple.com/us/album/permission-to-dance/1574770126?i=1574770128&uo=4",
            "previewUrl": "https://audio-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets/AudioPreview125/v4/e1/6e/12/e16e1227-97a2-acf8-e3e0-6685f746695a/mzaf_12664711249777906736.plus.aac.p.m4a",
            "artworkUrl30": "https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music125/v4/cd/9b/1f/cd9b1fec-28b4-cbb9-42f5-adffcfbeba36/source/30x30bb.jpg",
            "artworkUrl60": "https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music125/v4/cd/9b/1f/cd9b1fec-28b4-cbb9-42f5-adffcfbeba36/source/60x60bb.jpg",
            "artworkUrl100": "https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Music125/v4/cd/9b/1f/cd9b1fec-28b4-cbb9-42f5-adffcfbeba36/source/100x100bb.jpg",
            "collectionPrice": 0.69,
            "trackPrice": 0.69,
            "releaseDate": "2021-07-09T12:00:00Z",
            "collectionExplicitness": "notExplicit",
            "trackExplicitness": "notExplicit",
            "discCount": 1,
            "discNumber": 1,
            "trackCount": 1,
            "trackNumber": 1,
            "trackTimeMillis": 187585,
            "country": "USA",
            "currency": "USD",
            "primaryGenreName": "K-Pop",
            "isStreamable": false
        }
    ]
}
```

To map the response to the view you need to do something like this:

```
fetch(`https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=${event.target.dataset.id}`)
    .then(resp => resp.json())
    .then(data  => {
        const song = data.results[0];
        if (song) {        
            info.innerHTML += `
            <h1>${song.trackName}</h1>
            <h3>Artist Name: </h3>
            <p>${song.artistName}</p>
            <h3>Release Date: </h3>
            <p>${song.releaseDate}</p>
            `;
        }
    })
```

Comment: Do I need to change anything else?

Comment: Even when I changed it I still get undefined

Comment: Use the second structure